# Regex .* not matching a lack of input

Tags: regex, match

Hi I have the following regex statement:-

```
<a .* href="http://www.someurl/test.htm">.*?<\/a>
```

That matches the following just fine:-

```
<a class=op_web href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">Test</a>
```

However it doesnt match when there is nothing entered between the opening 'a' tag and the 'href' statement e.g.:-

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">Test</a>
```

How do I rearrange this statement so that it can match anything at all between the opening 'a' and the 'href' including nothing at all?

Comment: @vks's answer is correct - however your regex looks a bit suspect, eg the `.`s in the URL will also be matching any character, not just `.` - you need to escape them.

Comment: @JamesThorpe not only that, he needs to match the inbetween `.co.uk`

Comment: @AvinashRaj indeed - the `.` was just one example of what's wrong... the list would be a bit too long for a comment, and it's not an answer to the question asked either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a .* href="http://www.someurl/test.htm">.*?<\/a>
```

This is because of `spaces` after `<a` .Make it

```
<a\b.*href="http:\/\/www\.someurl\.co\.uk\/test\.htm">.*?<\/a>
```

Try

```
<a\b(?:(?!<\/a>).)*href="http:\/\/www\.someurl\.co\.uk\/test\.htm">(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/66

Comment: Why does the following string not match? vitae dicta sunt `<a href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">explicabo</a>`.

Comment: It doesn't with the "vitae dicta sunt" text before it, I am looking to use it to find and replace links within a block of text so there will be normal text either side of the link.

Comment: If I remove the anchors that isnt happy if I have more than 1 link in the text e.g. `dicta sunt <a href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">explicabo</a>. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni <a test1 href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">dolores</a> eos qui`

Answer (score 0):

You were getting issues because you have left space between `'.*'` which caused the regex engine to expect a space before and after it. You can try the below regex.

```
<a.*href="(\S+)">.*</a>
```

```
$ grep -Po '<a.*href="(\S+)">.*</a>' file.txt 
<a class=op_web href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">Test</a>
<a href="http://www.someurl.co.uk/test.htm">Test</a>
```